High CPU usage by process with obfuscated name on Linux server – Potential attack?
We have been experiencing high load issues on our Linux server recently. Upon checking with the
top

command, we noticed an unknown process with a garbled command name (as shown in following images; notice that the command name would change after rebooting). This process is consuming a significant amount of CPU resources.


We attempted to locate the executable path of this suspicious process, and the server returned the result shown below. The path indicates that the executable file has been deleted:
/proc/4747/exe -> '/ac1e4262 (deleted)'

From what I understand, this could mean that the process is still running even though its executable file has been removed. This situation might be indicative of a trojan or other malicious activity.
My questions:

Is this high CPU usage by an unknown process with a garbled command name likely caused by a trojan or some other form of malware?
What steps should I take to investigate and resolve this issue to ensure the security and stability of our server?


My first guess would be a cryptocurrency miner but I don't really know much about this kind of thing. Are you looking for an answer other than the obvious "wipe everything and restore from a clean backup"? If an attacker has gained root access to your server, there is no way to be certain you have cleaned up unless you do a clean wipe and restore.

A suspicious aspect is that when I restart the system, this program runs automatically, but when I use the nvidia-smi command, I find that the GPU memory is not being used. Another situation is that sometimes when I am running a program on the GPU, the execution speed suddenly slows down, making it feel like my program has been deprived of access to the GPU.

A crypto miner probably.

How many cores does this linux box have?   a load average of ~8 suggests 8 cores, but the process is using 25,369% of a core, suggesting ~254 cores?     4399 minutes of CPU time in this process with only 16 minutes of uptime also suggests ~260 cores.     What distro is this?

Welcome to Unix & Linux! Your image of text isn't very helpful.  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

The system is Ubuntu22.04, and the number of cores is 64. I don't know why the load is so high......

@terdon Typically the better response to a security incident/compromise is to snapshot the system, take it offline, and try to figure out how the compromise happened. By simply wiping and restoring, you run the risk of leaving the original entry point (or vuln) in place, and you're back to square one. How do you know which backup is safe? Modern ransomware can sit silent for months before activating. If this is a company server and not personal, you may want to consider engaging a cyber incident response company to look into this for you.

Oh yes, absolutely, @bob, I just meant you don't want to keep the infected version online and try to fix it.

There was a very similar question in this site few years ago: Process with weird random name consuming significant network and CPU resources. Is someone hacking me?. In that specific question, there was a known tojan.
In this answer, I'll only answer one of your questions:

"What steps should I take to investigate [the process]?"

The result of the investigation can help you reach an answer to your first question.
But you can start with:
Investigation tips
Look at its parents:
pstree -sap <pid>

If the parent is not init (1), than it might give you some idea of where it came from.
Check if it belongs to some systemd service
systemctl status <pid>

Check the full command line of the process.
In top you can toggle the full command line by press on c, or you can use ps:
ps -o args -p <pid>

Analyze the executable
You can copy the file to the disk (even though it's deleted) to analyze it.
cp /proc/<pid>/exe /tmp/suspicious_file
file /tmp/suspicious_file

Don't try to run it, but you might want to try to read it, and look for additional hints. Since this is probably a binary, you can use commands such as strings / hexdump / od / xxd to inspect its content.

Notice that running ldd to inspect it is a risk, because that works by executing the program.

Check its environment variables
Maybe it will give you another hint:
xargs -0 printf "%s\n" < /proc/<pid>/environ

Check which other files this process holds open
lsof -p <pid>

It might be, for instance, writing logs to file that you could read, or maybe even has some network sockets open.
Check the logs
You can try checking in your logs what happened on the machine around the time the process started.
To get the exact time it started:
ps -o lstart -p <pid>

And look in different logs (like journalctl, on systemd machines) if anything suspicious happened around this time, or if you can get any insights.
journalctl -S 'YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM'

Did anyone enter your machine using ssh maybe? or someone ran sudo command? You might find those in the logs.
BTW, You can convert the date you get from ps to the format readable by journcalctl by using the date command, something like that:
date  +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M" --date="$(ps --no-header -olstart -p <PID>)"


Only after you get sufficient data, you can use it to reach an informed decision.
About the other part of the question, I highly recommend reading How do I deal with a compromised server? on ServerFault (which was also suggested by the accepted answer to the first question I shared). The first answer is very long and detailed, but as the answers says:

First things first, there are no "quick fixes" other than restoring your system from a backup taken prior to the intrusion, and this has
at least two problems.

It's difficult to pinpoint when the intrusion happened.
It doesn't help you close the "hole" that allowed them to break in last time, nor deal with the consequences of any "data theft" that may
also have taken place.



To analyze the executable, I would add strings if it wasn't stripped, which is also a huge hint.

You forgot, "take the machine off the net".  I'm also not certain treating a compromised system as something you might be able to fix is healthy. If the system is compromised, then it's not yours anymore. Reinstall and use latest known good backups of data.  If you want to do forensics, then do so offline and separately.

In some places, depending on who owns the system, you are also obliged to report things like these to authorities. A workplace would have routines for this.

"It moght be a completely legit process" - it sure doesn't smell that way...

@Kusalananda, I agree with not "treating a compromised system as something you might be able to fix".  However, if the investigation determines that it's innocent (seems unlikely to me, but could be possible), then it's reasonable to reconnect it at that point.

I don't think that /proc/$pid/exe can ever be a script - if the kernel uses an interpreter (via shebang or binfmt mechanism), then the interpreter is the target of that link.  Worth mentioning that using ldd to inspect it is a risk, because that works by executing the program.  Not everyone knows that.

@TobySpeight: Hasn't been the case for a while. In current glibc versions it explicitly runs the system's ld.so instead of trusting the binary's headers.

Regarding the first tip: If the parent process is init (or in any case really), cat /proc/<pid>/cgroup (as well as systemctl status <pid>) will show which cgroup the process runs in, which a non-root process generally cannot escape no matter the amount of forking it does.

@athena even if it was stripped, strings may reveal FQDNs and URLs, filenames and paths, error messages...

@u1686_grawity - the picture does show it running as root, unfortunately (and worryingly).

@Kusalananda : "You forgot, "take the machine off the net""  . How right you are![↵]First: ifconfig en0 down in case this is a fast replicating crapware. Avoid propagation to your home or your company. I had to fight viruses able to replicate at 1000 PC / s ( ping, test, in )… 10 years ago.

My answers:

no; garbled command names is nothing new and that alone does not mean it is malware.  As for it being unknown... you see a UFO does that mean it's aliens coming to take over no, it just means it is unidentified and you don't know.  First step is "knowing".

As for steps you didn't mention what Linux operating system or any other technical information but  (in my opinion) if/when such a situation arises it is easiest for me to reformat the disk and cleanly reinstall RHEL from .iso then cleanly reinstall & reconfigure all software which guarantees a solution.  If you have your shtuff together this can be quick.  Otherwise you have to do legwork finding what is running...

comparing installed stuff with their original hash via rpm -VA is a first step however I think this has its problems for various reasons  https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_6/2020-09-03/finding/V-218099
use fapolicyd which is application whitelisting which may block the offending process however this is not foolproof either; when an app is blocked it will be in audit.log (i think).  https://docs.redhat.com/en/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/security_hardening/assembly_blocking-and-allowing-applications-using-fapolicyd_security-hardening
narrow down the runlevel (1, 3, or 5) for where the offending process is happening in to help narrow down where to search.
begin going through all the systemctl list-unit-files and first be able to identify all are legitimate and then take a stab at which might possibly be contributing to the offending process and begin disabling services to troubleshoot, and go through software install logs and evaluate user activity.
check over the filesystem permissions and configuration, and logs, looking for any blatant security holes like known users su'ing to root who shouldn't be, files/folders having writable/executable permissions that shouldn't have.




It's not just the messed up name, but the fact it changes every boot that makes it very suspicious.

fair enough however it's not surprising that it changes after every boot... if it's a name that's getting mangled.  Would be like using an un-initialized variable in code which would have some different value.  You just don't really know.
